# If $B$ is a small perturbation of positive-definite matrix $A$, then do we have $B>\epsilon A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite

Suppose $A=(a_{ij})$ is a (symmetric) positive-definite matrix, and $B$ is another symmetric matrix.

> **Question**: If $B$ is in a small neighborhood $U$ of $A$, then it seems that $B$ should also be positive-definite. Moreover for what value of $\epsilon>0$ we can find a neighborhood $U$ so that $B>\epsilon A$?

If both $A$ and $B$ are diagonal matrices, then this is trivial. But in general since we can only diagonalize one of them and I am afraid there will be some issue.

Comment: When you say $B$ is in a small neighborhood of $A$, do you mean that $\|B-A\| < \epsilon$ (operator norm), $\|B-A\|_F < \epsilon$ (Frobenius norm), or some other norm?

Comment: I just mean the topology of $\mathbb R^{n^2}$, but I think I am also interested in the question for different topology.

Comment: @Hang You can find some discussion on the topic here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/226486/the-openness-of-the-set-of-positive-definite-square-matrices

Comment: You can always find a PDS diagonal matrix as close as you want to the zero matrix. Does this help?

Comment: @Wintermute What does PDS stand for?

Comment: @Hang PDS = positive definite symmetric

Answer (score 1):

If you consider $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$, then that does not work because $B$ may be non-symmetric. Thus we assume that $B=A+H$ where the small matrix $H$ goes through the vector space of symmetric matrices.

Let $spectrum(A)=\{\lambda_1\leq\cdots \leq \lambda_n\}$ (note that $\lambda_1>0$). Let $\epsilon\in[0,1)$ and $\alpha >0$ (to be determined). Since the norms are equivalent, we'll use the spectral norm defined, on the symmetric matrices, by $||S||=\rho(S)$ (the spectral radius of $S$).

We assume that $||H||<\alpha$, that implies $x^TBx\geq x^TAx-\alpha$ when $||x||_2^2=1$ (that we suppose in the sequel).

We choose $\alpha<\lambda_1$. Then $x^TBx\geq \lambda_1-\alpha >0$ and $B$ is symmetric$>0$.

Now $x^T(B-\epsilon A)x\geq x^TAx(1-\epsilon)-\alpha\geq \lambda_1(1-\epsilon)-\alpha$.

We choose $\alpha<\lambda_1(1-\epsilon)$. Then $B>\epsilon A$.

Comment: Thank you, but actually I have assumed $B$ is symmetric.

Comment: Me also my friend. Try to understand my post.

Comment: I do not understand why we cannot simply use the subspace topology in the space of symmetric matrices induced from the topology of $\mathbb R^{n^2}$.

Comment: Yes, the induced topology is the correct expression